# Resample pandas DataFrame spanning several years

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Series that looks like this:

```
df.index[0:10]

DatetimeIndex(['1881-12-01', '1882-01-01', '1882-02-01', '1882-12-01',
           '1883-01-01', '1883-02-01', '1883-12-01', '1884-01-01',
           '1884-02-01', '1884-12-01'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', freq=None)
```

Now I'd like to resample it so that every December, January and February is grouped together. More generally: I'd like to resample a dataframe to contain yearly periods, ignoring NaNs, so that the first index is taken into consideration:

```
assert(df[0:3].mean() == df.resample(something).mean().iloc[0])
```

`df.resample('Y')` treats the first index as a separate year. How do I do that? I wrote a `partition` function that groups an interable into equally sized chunks but I feel like there's a more idiomatic (and potentially faster) way that I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this by using an anchored yearly offset as described [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets).